# VisualStudio2022 + React - The Js & TS language service has been disabled after crashing repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, intellisense

I created a new React standalone boilerplate app with VisualStudio 2022.
I was able to run the app but IntelliSense is completely failing.

Visual Studio Version:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview (64-bit) Version 17.0.0
> Preview 2.0

[image]

What can be reason for this or is there any way I can turn it on manualy?

Here's what I tried.

1. Checked “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript” directory - This is the default directory for Javascript and TypeScript language services. But I can't find a folder name with TypeScript there.
2. Checked If TypeScript SDK is installed - Opened VisualStudio installer but I can see TypeScript 4.2 SDK is already ticked. Not sure where it is installed. (Attached screenshot)
   [image]
3. Tried to generate logs from language service but the logs are not generating with the commands I tried. (Attached screenshot)
   [image]
4. This is my package.json
   [image]

Comment: Please have a try this: follow the error message and try to reload your solution(File > Close Solution > Open the solution again). Besides, does the `React standalone boilerplate app` you mentioned need to install some extensions to work or it is a default project template in Visual Studio? Perhaps you can share the way to reproduce your issue with us.

Comment: And on my side, I tested by using “Standalone JavaScript/TypeScript React Template”, I think they are (maybe) not what you mentioned right? I did install the Node.js development workload, Node.js, and kept every default settings, the project built well and there was no IntelliSense error.

Comment: I also checked and I have C:\Program Files (x86)\...\TypeScript directory. Not sure if you missed something or some files were corrupted, perhaps you can have a try reinstall the related things, for example reinstall Node.js(remember to select and install the related tools).

Comment: I tried restarting VS and reloading solution with no luck. I used VS default "Standalone Javascript React template" not TypeScript. I've Node.js and TypeScript SDK installed. Main thing is I'm using VisualStudio 2022 64bit Preview 2 as I mentioned above. TypeScript SDK 4.2 is ticked on VS Installer as I put screenshot above but don't know where it  recides

Comment: Yes, I tested with VS 2022 too. I can find TypeScript SDK 4.2 related packages under this directory `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\ Microsoft.VisualStudio.TypeScript.Sdk.4.2,version=4.2.XXXXXX`, but I’m not sure if it is also installed separately at other location.

Comment: Same issues on my side.Really a poor 3experience with vs 2022

Comment: I got in to same issue, reason was while using VS Code I was not able to install Typescript, every time npm completes Typescript setup but version stays 1.0 I google the issue where most of ppl said to delete the folder at `C:\Program Files (x86)\...\TypeScript` after deleting it worked, but but javascript typescrip service went down, now I understand what was happening at that time